# Howto pipe to perl a daemon in execution

Tags: perl

I know how to pipe to a perl script just executing something like this:

```
command | script.pl
```

Inside the script.pl I got the:

```
while(<STDIN>){...
```

and so on, but I demonized the script and i want to know how can I pipe a command to the script while is running like a daemon.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

STDIN should be closed on daemonization for security reasons.

You need to create a socket (or perhaps a fifo) and read from that. I would suggest [Unix domain sockets](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aUNIX), see chapter 17.6 of the [Perl Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003135/).

It is difficult to be more precise from here, as it depends on what your daemon does.

---

**Update:**

Actually, now that I think about it, if the program is run on a *nix box you could keep your script as it is and use [inetd](http://xinetd.org/) instead. Inetd will listen to a socket for you and start your daemon on connection, bridging between the socket and STDIN/STDOUT on your program. I have no experience with using inetd with domain sockets, but superficial googling indicates that at least some implementations support domain sockets.

Comment: The reason for closing stdin is not related to security but to completely disassociate the deamon from the environment where it was launched.

Comment: @salva: OP has a program that can interact with the user via stdin and can also act as a daemon. I posit that this program should make sure that it can not be "reached" via stdin when deamonized. To me this is a security precation. Most daemons does not have this duality but should still close stdin in order to disociate themselves from the terminal so as not to keep it from being recycled.